# Controlling Javascript Selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

The following codes makes div appear sequentially.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.word1, .word2, .word3').each(function(fadeIn) {
      $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
```

```css
  .chat {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
  <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
  
  
  <div id="" class="">Word 4</div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is, I don't want it to appear in a sequence. I can do it by simply replacing elements in an html, for example I can do:

```
  <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
  <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
```

However, I don't want to change anything on the html elements. I want to do it using javascript. At first, I thought javascript selector works like an array and I can replace

`$('.word1, .word2, .word3') with $('.word2, .word1, .word3')`

but it does not seems to work that way.

Is there a way to do this with `Javascript`?

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve, but looks like you want the html show not in the order it was written. you could use css flex order (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) or jquery sortable (https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Comment: That's right, not in order. I'll give it a try tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here be a solution if you do not want to change your HTML(and incase css also):

1. Keep the shuffle Position in array.
2. Iterate all div having class `chat`.
3. Put the `DOM element` in `new array` based on shuffle Position.
4. Iterate all `element` of `new array` and `append` in `body`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var shufflePosition=[1,0,2];//Keep the shufflePosition in array
 var result=[];

 //Iterate all div having class chat
 $('.chat').get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
     result[index]=array[shufflePosition[index]];
 });

 for (var i = result.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $( "body" ).last().prepend(result[i]);
    //$(result[i]).show();
    $(result[i]).delay(i*500).fadeIn(1000);
 }
});
```

```css
.chat {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
  <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
  <div id="" class="">Word 4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Avoid $.remove in this case. It's a complicated method that goes deep inside the element to remove all data and events attached to it, instead in such a case, you might prefer $.detach. But in this exact case, `$.prepend` is just enough, ParentNode.appendChild method takes care of removing the node if in DOM.

Comment: Hi NullPointer, this is what I need, but how do you apply fadetoggle on it?

Comment: Oh, it's all good now, I was able to figure it out. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You use a *query selector*:

```
var word1 = document.querySelectorAll(".chat", ".word1")[0];
```

This selects the first element with both classes `.chat` and `.word1`.

Comment: No problem whatsoever!

Comment: What is this second param?

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chat').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
  });
```

```css
  .chat {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
  <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
  
  
  <div id="" class="">Word 4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont understand what exactly you want. but if you want show word1,word2,word3 at once my answer will works

Comment: Hi, i want to be able to show those divs not order. Currently it shows in order. I can do it by changing divs but i want to do it using javascript.

Comment: OK. you want div shows one by one and it works well. your problem is that you want mix div orders 
EX) 
word1
word3
word2 
OR
word2
word1
word3
is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution, to not care about the order of the Divs, is:

```
$('.chat').each(function(fadeIn) {
    $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

You should define a common class for these randomly ordered elements, or wrap them with a parent element, eg:

```
$('.randomlysortedelements div').each(function(fadeIn) {
    $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
});

<body>
  <div class="randomlysortedelements">
    <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
    <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
    <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="" class="">Word 4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Tony-OP already mentioned that he don't want to change the HTML.so in this case you solution will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle your array length and [prependTo](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) to word4 something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 elements =  $('.word1, .word2, .word3');
 let arrayData = [];
 for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
 arrayData.push(i);
 }
 
 shuffleArray(arrayData);
 for(i=0;i<arrayData.length;i++){ 
   $("body:last").prepend(elements.eq(arrayData[i]));
   elements.eq(arrayData[i]).show()
 }
    
    
    function shuffleArray(array) {
      for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          var temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[j];
          array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.chat {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
  <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
  
  
  <div id="" class="word4">Word 4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: -OP already mentioned that he don't want to change the HTML.so in this case you solution will work?

Comment: OP said he don't wants to change in the HTML of 1,2,3 4 is not stated anywhere.

Comment: >>However, I don't want to change anything on the html elements. I want to do it using javascript.

Comment: @NullPointer will you append all the options at the end of the body? does that makes sense?